# Create open constructed type from string

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Let's say I have the following class.

```
MyClass<T>
{
    public void MyMethod(T a, List<T> b, List<Tuple<T, string>> c) {}
}
```

I can get the type of the arguments of the method as follow

```
Type testType = typeof(MyClass<>);
MethodInfo myMethodInfo = testType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
Type[] paramTypes = myMethodInfo.GetParameters().Select(pi => pi.ParameterType);
```

How can I manually create an array containing the **same open types** as `paramTypes` from a string? For ex from

```
var typesAsStr = new string[] {"T", "List`1[T]", "List`1[Tuple`2[T, string]]"};
```

**If** I had `MyClass<int>`, I could do something like `Type.GetType(fullQualifiedNameOfArg)` for each argument, **but** here I want to keep the generic argument T:

- I can't create "a": I can't do `Type.GetType("T")`
- I can almost create "b": I can do `Type.GetType("List` `` `1") ``, but the info on "T" is not yet present
- I don't know how to create "c"

I ended up needing this when converting a Mono.Cecil type into a .net type: Cecil gives me the info on a method named `"MyMethod"` with arguments `"T"`, `"List<T>"` and `"List<Tuple<T, string>>"`. I then want to get that method using reflection (if there are several methods with the same name and argument numbers, I have to check the args to know which one it is), that's why I'd want to have a way to transform what Cecil tells me into what .Net knows, to be able to compare with what's in `paramTypes`.

I've also seen several other people asking how to convert a Mono.Cecil type into a .Net one, so that's also why I thought I'd try.

Comment: What do you mean by "same types as 'paramTypes' from a string?"? Do you mean a string which contains the qualified name of a type?

Comment: @eulerfx: for ex I have: var myTypesAsString = new string[] {"T", "List`1[T]", "List`1[Tuple`2[T, string]]"};

Comment: Do you really need to create the array of types, or do you need to identify the method which has parameters from the input string describing them?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks. I would choose my approach mostly for the performance and simplicity. But I must give a point (and in fact I +1-d) that despite complexity (string parsing, generic type parameter resolution), WarenG's approach is really good. But is that feasible? - we'll see.

Comment: @Tengiz What I currently need is to identify the right method, so really creating the Type may not be necessary. I'd still be interested to know if it's possible (still need to check WarenG's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `T` using strings, you do it by calling `GetType` with the string name of `MyClass` and then getting the generic arguments of the resulting type.  From there you can build up the other open generic types using `MakeGenericType`.  You have to work from the inside out by constructing the most nested types first.  To do it automatically across differing methods would require some string parsing to get to the nested types.  For the sake of comparing .Net methods against Cecil methods, @Tengiz might have a better approach.

To run the code, update the string name of `MyClass` to have the correct namespace for your environment.

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {
    // change 'yournamespace'
    Type testType = Type.GetType("yournamespace.MyClass`1");
    Type[] testTypeGenericArgs = testType.GetGenericArguments();

    // Get T type from MyClass generic args
    Type tType = testTypeGenericArgs[0];

    Type genericListType = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1");

    // create type List<T>
    Type openListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(testTypeGenericArgs[0]);
    Type genericTuple = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`2");
    Type stringType = Type.GetType("System.String");

    // create type Tuple<T, string>
    Type openTuple = genericTuple.MakeGenericType(new[] { tType, stringType });

    // create type List<Tuple<T, string>>
    Type openListOfTuple = genericListType.MakeGenericType(openTuple);

    Type[] typesFromStrings = new[] { tType, openListType, openListOfTuple };

    // get method parameters per example
    Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass<>);
    MethodInfo myMethodInfo = myClassType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
    Type[] paramTypes = myMethodInfo.GetParameters().Select(pi => pi.ParameterType).ToArray();

    // compare type created from strings against types
    // retrieved by reflection
    for (int i = 0; i < typesFromStrings.Length; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(typesFromStrings[i].Equals(paramTypes[i]));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Although complex, to me this seems to be the universal solution to the given problem. Plus, for methods which take additional generic parameters, those type parameters must be resolved using method's type parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your POC, I should have thought of doing it like that! I'll try to update my current code to use your technique. Will get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

I found this so interesting, that I had to create something myself, and present it to the world... and after a couple hours of exploration, here is what I got...

### The extension method for Type: GetMethodByString

This is very simple: get a type and then call the method passing a string that represents the method you want:

```
var type = typeof(MyType<>);
type.GetMethodByString("MyMethod(T, List`1[T], List`1[Tuple`2[T, String]])")
```

**Sample program**

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var t1 = typeof(MyType<>);
        var mi11 = t1.GetMethodByString("MyMethod(T, List`1[T], List`1[Tuple`2[T, String]])");
        var mi12 = t1.GetMethodByString("Method[X](X, T)");
        var mi13 = t1.GetMethodByString("Method(List`1[T], Int32 ByRef)");
        var t2 = typeof(MyType);
        var mi21 = t2.GetMethodByString("Method[X, T](List`1[X], Tuple`2[X, List`1[T]])");
    }

    class MyType<T>
    {
        public void MyMethod(T a, List<T> b, List<Tuple<T, string>> c) { }
        public void Method(List<T> t, out int i) { i = 0; }
        public void Method<X>(X x, T t) { }
    }

    class MyType
    {
        public int Method<X, T>(List<X> x, Tuple<X, List<T>> tuple)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**TypeExtensions**

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static MethodInfo GetMethodByString(
        this Type type, string methodString)
    {
        return type.GetMethods()
            .Where(mi => MethodToString(mi) == methodString)
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static string MethodToString(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        var b = new StringBuilder();
        b.Append(mi.Name);
        if (mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
            b.AppendFormat("[{0}]",
                string.Join(", ", mi.GetGenericArguments()
                .Select(TypeToString)));
        b.AppendFormat("({0})", string.Join(", ", mi.GetParameters()
            .Select(ParamToString)));
        return b.ToString();
    }

    public static string TypeToString(Type t)
    {
        var b = new StringBuilder();
        b.AppendFormat("{0}", t.Name);
        if (t.IsGenericType)
            b.AppendFormat("[{0}]",
                string.Join(", ", t.GetGenericArguments()
                .Select(TypeToString)));
        return b.ToString();
    }

    public static string ParamToString(ParameterInfo pi)
    {
        return TypeToString(pi.ParameterType).Replace("&", " ByRef");
    }
}
```

### Why I didn't try to get types by name

Unfortunately, I found no way to get a type given a string, unless you guess a lot about the type being represented... so, it is quite impossible.

That explains why I did a method to find the method instead. It is much more precise... but it could eventually fail, in very rare and bizarre circumstances:

- if you create a List of your own, and then two overloads of the same method, one taking the .Net List and the other taking the List you have created... then it fails

### Why not parsing the input string

I found that for the purpose of looking up a method, it is enough to have a fixed syntax string, so that I can generate it from the method and compare... that have some limitations:

- must use the name of the type, so C# alliases won't work (`string` must be named "String", `int` must be named "Int32" not "int")

**EDIT**

### Performance

This solution is not very performatic, but nothing that a cache cannot solve. The method could use a dictionary, using both the Type and the string as a composite key, and look in there before trying to find the method by bulding a lot of strings and comparing all of them.

If you need thread safety on the cache dictionary, use a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`... very nice class.

**EDIT 2: Created a cached version**

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>> cacheOfGetMethodByString
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>>();

public static MethodInfo GetMethodByString(
    this Type type, string methodString)
{
    var typeData = cacheOfGetMethodByString
        .GetOrAdd(type, CreateTypeData);
    MethodInfo mi;
    typeData.TryGetValue(methodString, out mi);
    return mi;
}

public static Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> CreateTypeData(Type type)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();
    foreach (var eachMi in type.GetMethods())
        dic.Add(MethodToString(eachMi), eachMi);
    return dic;
}
```

Hoppe this helps! =)

Comment: Thanks for taking part of the fun! I know I had fun playing with those generics. Your method should indeed work in most cases, and it's pretty simple. Just for the fun of it I'm playing with @WarrenG's idea, and it works quite well. It's a lot more complex and I end up with quite a lot of methods, but the more the merrier, right?

Comment: @user276648: I think so! In fact I explored a lot of different paths... including some of the other answers as well... and I learned some new things. But I felt something was missing: simplicity... and this is a quality for itself, and it was what motivated my answer.

Comment: @user276648: Hope you can have some fun, and also learn some new things! =)

Comment: Hi again! I have created a cached version of the method (see *EDIT 2*)... so if it is called more than a few times, it may be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks again for you clean code. I like your AppendFormat with Join and Select to do everything in one line, never thought of it. It indeed makes your code really readable. I'll still go with WarrenG's answer as being able to really get the type was something I was also interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think .NET allows you to *create* a type "T" where T is a type argument, **which is yet to be specified**. So, the array of `Type`(s) from input string array cannot be created.

However, in the second part of your question, I read that you want to *identify* the method which has those types given as string. That task is solvable by iterating though the arguments, creating another array of strings describing the method arguments, and then comparing the resulting and input arrays, as follows:

```
    class MyClass<T>
    {
        public void MyMethod(T a, List<T> b, List<Tuple<T, string>> c) { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //input.
            var typesAsStr = new string[] { "T", "List`1[T]", "List`1[Tuple`2[T, string]]" };

            //type to find a method.
            Type testType = typeof(MyClass<>);
            //possibly iterate through methods instead?
            MethodInfo myMethodInfo = testType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
            //get array of strings describing MyMethod's arguments.
            string[] paramTypes = myMethodInfo.GetParameters().Select(pi => TypeToString(pi.ParameterType)).ToArray();

            //compare arrays of strings (can be improved).
            var index = -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Method found: {0}", typesAsStr.All(str => { index++; return index < paramTypes.Length && str == paramTypes[index]; }));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static CSharpCodeProvider compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        private static string TypeToString(Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType) {
                return type.Name + "[" + string.Join(", ", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(ga => TypeToString(ga))) + "]";
            }
            else if (type.IsGenericParameter) {
                return type.Name;
            }

            //next line gives "string" (lower case for System.String).
            //additional type name translations can be applied if output is not what we neeed.
            return compiler.GetTypeOutput(new CodeTypeReference(type));
        }
    }
```

In the [console] output I see that your input string **matches** the function.

BTW, a lot of optimizations can be applied to this code if you face the performance problems, such as efficient way of working with strings, releasing `CSharpCodeProvider` instance maybe, etc. But the code is enough to solve the given task as questioned.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at your answer in more details. As for the optimization part, I don't really care as it's just for tests to be run by the CI server.

Comment: "which is yet to be specified": indeed, if the type is defined by the class, it's easy to get using WarrenG's approach. If the type is defined by the method, then we end up with a circular issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are trying to do, but there is a relatively easy way of achieving the same result by entering from a different direction

#### Strings do not identify types uniquely

This is the basic problem with converting strings to types: when you see a `T`, you have no idea where it came from. The following is a valid class definition:

```
class Simple<T> {
    public T Make(T blah) {
        return blah;
    }
    public T Make<T>(T blah) {
        return blah;
    }
}
```

Two overloads of `Make` have parameters that look identical, yet they do not compare as equal. Moreover, there is absolutely no way of getting the `T` of the generic `Make<T>` without first getting the `MethodInfo` for the generic `Make<T>` - a circular dependency.

#### What can you do?

Instead of going for the impossible `string`->`Type` conversion, you can build a *matcher* that tells you if an instance of a type, including an unbounded generic type, matches a given string representation:

```
static bool MatchType(string str, Type type)
```

With this method in hand, you can walk through all available methods with a particular name, and check the types of their parameter lists one by one against the strings in your array of strings:

```
var typesAsStr = new [] {"T", "List`1[T]", "List`1[Tuple`2[T, string]]"};
var myMethod = typeof (Simple<>)
    .GetMethods()
    .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "MyMethod" &&
        typesAsStr
            .Zip(m.GetParameters(), (s, t) => new {s, t})
            .All(p => MatchType(p.s, p.t.ParameterType))
    );
```

#### How do you implement the `MatchType` method?

You can use a technique similar to [*Recursive Descent Parsing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser): tokenize your string, and then match elements of your type as you go through the chain of tokens. When a class is parameterized, get generic parameters and match them recursively. You need to pay attention to array types, but that is relatively simple as well. Take a look:

```
public static bool MatchType(string str, Type type) {
    var queue = new Queue<Token>(Tokenize(str));
    return MatchRecursive(queue, type) && (queue.Count == 0);
}
private static bool MatchRecursive(Queue<Token> tokens, Type type) {
    string baseName;
    if (!ReadToken(tokens, TokenType.Identifier, out baseName)) return false;
    var ranks = new List<int>();
    while (type.IsArray) {
        ranks.Add(type.GetArrayRank());
        type = type.GetElementType();
    }
    if (type.IsGenericType) {
        if (!type.Name.StartsWith(baseName+"`") || !DropToken(tokens, TokenType.Tick)) return false;
        string numStr;
        int num;
        if (!ReadToken(tokens, TokenType.Number, out numStr)
        ||  !int.TryParse(numStr, out num)
        ||  !DropToken(tokens, TokenType.OpenBraket)) return false;
        var genParams = type.GetGenericArguments();
        if (genParams.Length != num) return false;
        for (var i = 0 ; i < num ; i++) {
            if (i != 0 && !DropToken(tokens, TokenType.Comma)) return false;
            if (!MatchRecursive(tokens, genParams[i])) return false;
        }
        if (!DropToken(tokens, TokenType.CloseBraket)) return false;
    }
    foreach (var rank in ranks) {
        if (!DropToken(tokens, TokenType.OpenBraket)) return false;
        for (var i = 0 ; i != rank-1 ; i++) {
            if (!DropToken(tokens, TokenType.Comma)) return false;
        }
        if (!DropToken(tokens, TokenType.CloseBraket)) return false;
    }
    return type.IsGenericType || Aliases.Contains(new Tuple<string, Type>(baseName, type)) || type.Name == baseName;
}

private static readonly ISet<Tuple<string,Type>> Aliases = new HashSet<Tuple<string, Type>> {
    new Tuple<string, Type>("bool", typeof(bool)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("byte", typeof(byte)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("sbyte", typeof(sbyte)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("char", typeof(char)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("string", typeof(string)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("short", typeof(short)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("ushort", typeof(ushort)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("int", typeof(int)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("uint", typeof(uint)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("long", typeof(long)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("ulong", typeof(ulong)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("float", typeof(float)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("double", typeof(double)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("decimal", typeof(decimal)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("void", typeof(void)),
    new Tuple<string, Type>("object", typeof(object))
};
private enum TokenType {
    OpenBraket,
    CloseBraket,
    Comma,
    Tick,
    Identifier,
    Number
}
private class Token {
    public TokenType Type { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public Token(TokenType type, string text) {
        Type = type;
        Text = text;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", Enum.GetName(typeof(TokenType), Type), Text);
    }
}
private static bool DropToken(Queue<Token> tokens, TokenType expected) {
    return (tokens.Count != 0) && (tokens.Dequeue().Type == expected);
}
private static bool ReadToken(Queue<Token> tokens, TokenType expected, out string text) {
    var res = (tokens.Count != 0) && (tokens.Peek().Type == expected);
    text = res ? tokens.Dequeue().Text : null;
    return res;
}
private static IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(IEnumerable<char> str) {
    var res = new List<Token>();
    var text = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in str) {
        var pos = "[],`".IndexOf(c);
        if ((pos != -1 || char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) && text.Length != 0) {
            res.Add(new Token(
                char.IsDigit(text[0]) ? TokenType.Number : TokenType.Identifier
            ,   text.ToString())
            );
            text.Clear();
        }
        if (pos != -1) {
            res.Add(new Token((TokenType)pos, c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        } else if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c)) {
            text.Append(c);
        }
    }
    if (text.Length != 0) {
        res.Add(new Token(
            char.IsDigit(text[0]) ? TokenType.Number : TokenType.Identifier
        ,   text.ToString())
        );
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/MwWfiB). I needed to modify it to comply with the 3.5 LINQ, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks. "Recursive Descent Parsing": actually I thought this might be feasible using something like antlr. But as I've never used any, it would probably take me more time to learn that tool than to do the parsing myself.

Comment: @user276648 There is no tool to learn here: my answer contains a fully working and debugged implementation of a simple recursive descent parser (that's the `MatchRecursive` function). Just copy-paste it into your program, and try it out. Most of it is self-explanatory: set a break point on `MatchRecursive`, and step through the method to see what happens. The implementation supports generic types and multi-dimension arrays.

Comment: @user276648 Note that parsing is more "forgiving" than relying on built-in C# libraries to construct strings that match what's coming out of Cecil, because you have full control over aliases, whitespace, and other details of the text structure.

Comment: Indeed there's no tool to learn with your solution. I was just saying that I thought of parsing the string, and thus use something like Antlr, but as I never used Antlr, it would take me a lot of time to make it work, but I'd learn something new...Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @user276648 You are welcome! Part of this solution is from a piece of code that has been working flawlessly in production for some 4.5 years now. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me what the exactly you need, but  i believe you can use the following technique:

```
object[] parameters = CreateParameters(typeof(MyClass<>), "MyMethod", typeof(int));
Debug.Assert(parameters[0] is int);
Debug.Assert(parameters[1] is List<int>);
Debug.Assert(parameters[2] is List<Tuple<int, string>>);
//...
object[] CreateParameters(Type type, string methodName, Type genericArgument) {
    object[] parameters = null;
    MethodInfo mInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    if(mInfo != null) {
        var pInfos = mInfo.GetParameters();
        parameters = new object[pInfos.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < pInfos.Length; i++) {
            Type pType = pInfos[i].ParameterType;
            if(pType.IsGenericParameter)
                parameters[i] = Activator.CreateInstance(genericArgument);
            if(pType.IsGenericType) {
                var arguments = ResolveGenericArguments(pType, genericArgument);
                Type definition = pType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                Type actualizedType = definition.MakeGenericType(arguments);
                parameters[i] = Activator.CreateInstance(actualizedType);
            }
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}
Type[] ResolveGenericArguments(Type genericType, Type genericArgument) {
    Type[] arguments = genericType.GetGenericArguments();
    for(int i = 0; i < arguments.Length; i++) {
        if(arguments[i].IsGenericParameter)
            arguments[i] = genericArgument;
        if(arguments[i].IsGenericType) {
            var nestedArguments = ResolveGenericArguments(arguments[i], genericArgument);
            Type nestedDefinition = arguments[i].GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            arguments[i] = nestedDefinition.MakeGenericType(nestedArguments);
        }
    }
    return arguments;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but actually I don't want to create an instance of my type, nor even fully resolve it (ie I really want to generate what's in my "paramTypes").